# Is it correct that in the SurveyMonkey API call I cannot choose the fields but instead have to pull in everything?

Tags: surveymonkey, klipfolio

I'd like to pull in data from SurveyMonkey into Klipfolio.

This is the api call that basically does the trick:

`https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/{props.surveyID}/responses/bulk`

(obviously, there would need to be some value inside the brackets.

However, this API call also pulls in the IP address and this I do not want. I'd rather choose some specific fields.
I believe this can't be done. However, I hope I'm missing something here.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:
`https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/{props.surveyID}/responses/bulk?total`

Couldn't find anything in the API documentation either, which is an argument for the case that it cannot be done. Rather, I hope I'm wrong and I'm just missing something.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The bulk endpoint provides all data associated with the response. If you don't need some of the data, you can simply not use it. That is unless you're constrained by some legal requirement, like GDPR, and are unable to prevent Klipfolio from storing that personally identifiable data.

Also take a look at the [SurveyMonkey-Klipfolio integration](https://www.klipfolio.com/integrations/surveymonkey-dashboard).